# Facade vs. Adapter design pattern using network a stream

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, adapter, facade

Let's assume that I have three SDK classes named Phone, DigitalClock and DigitalCompass which representing implicitly digital devices.

These classes supports:

- PC-to-Device and Device-to-PC data stream.
- operations like Connect-to-PC or Disconnect-from-PC.

Unfortunately, these classes **CANNOT** be changed and they don't inheritance from anything.

Now, I have a UDP service and TCP service that supports the following operations:

- Gets data and transmit it through the internet. (PC-to-NET)
- Receive data from the internet and return it. (NET-to-PC)

**Problem**: I want theese devices will be able to transmit and receive their streams through the internet.

**Solutions**:
I thought about two ways to design the above problem, i tested them and they both work:

1. Wrap every class with Facade-alike design pattern like so:

   - StreamablePhone,   StreamableDigitalClock and StreamableCompass.
   - Every wrapper class will inheritance from IStreamableDevice.

**Results**:
    Phone->streams to->StreamablePhone->sends to->UDP Service->transmits to->NET.

2. Wrap these classes with the Adapter design-pattern like so:

   - Adaptees: Phone, DigitalClock and DigitalCompass classes.
   - Adapters: The UDP service and the TCP service inheritance from interfaces(the following Targets) with matching names (IUdp* with UDP* service, ITcp with TCP service).
   - Targets:

     - UDP targets will be IUdpPhone, IUdpDigitalClock and IUdpDigitalCompass.
     - TCP targets will be ITcpPhone, ITcpDigitalClock nad ITcpDigitalCompass.

**Results**:
    Phone->streams to->IUdpPhone->transmit to->NET.

Which way should i choose to implement, consider it supports the scenario when more devices or more network services being add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main differences in both patterns are the intention of the developer implementing them. In short [Façade](http://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern) is:

> A single entry-point that represents an entire subsystem

While the [Adapter](http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern) will:

> Match interfaces of different classes

So in your case I'll go with the Façade, because you don't want to extend the functionality that is hidden from the *Phone*. What you're after (if i understand it correctly) is to simplify (and encapsulate) the communication between your sub-system and the Phone (end) devices. So the better match here is the Façade, since it defines a higher-level interface that makes the subsystem easier to use.  If you want to read a bit deeper layering it, there is a concept called 
[Federation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_(information_technology)) in the [Enterprise application integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_application_integration).

Another pattern that can be useful here is the [Command design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern), since it encapsulates a request as an object, thereby letting you parameterize clients with different requests, queue or log requests, and support undoable operations.

Comment: Thank you very much for well-detailed answer!